# is there any function similar to current_date for the week or previous week?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I will be having a new parquet file coming once in a week in my s3 bucket and my notebook runs daily. i would like to read that file into my notebook. every week i need to read the new file that is coming to my bucket

example:
file_name: XXXXXX_2022-06-15 and today is 19th of june and i want to read that file.

Is there any option where i can read it like the below:

import datetime
currentdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
print(currentdate)

spark.read.format("csv").load("s3://xxxxx + "/filename" + currentdate + ".parquet")

edited:   **So i am receiving a file once every monday in s3 bucket. and i need to pull that file and read it whole week and the next week its a new file thats need to be read every day for that week.**

Comment: Yes it should work , but what is it specifically you are looking for here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So i am receiving a file once every monday in s3 bucket. and i need to pull that file and read it whole week and the next week its a new file thats need to be read every day for that week.